# wpf xaml resource dictionary add custom property

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to use the following xaml code for navigation in some pages:

```
<Button Content="Go to page2">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Source" TargetObject="{Binding NavigationService, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}, Mode=FindAncestor}}">
                <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                    <System:Uri>Page2.xaml</System:Uri>
                </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
            </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

So I´m wondering if there is a possibility to outsource the interaction part into a style (in a resource dictionary) and add a custom property like "NavigationUri" where you can directly declare the page to navigate to.
Another idea (which would probably be the better approach) is to create a custom control and inherit from button class.
Anywhere I would prefer a more compact and lean way without code behind.

Please let me know, which is the more suitable solution and how to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are various simple techniques to make our Behavior Xaml as static resource. But, we need a custom behavior, as we are using a parameter in the form of Page name to navigate to. This variable demands programming.

So, I came up with

a. Custom behavior(NavigationBehavior), and

b. Button subclassing(NavigationButton)

**NavigationBehavior**

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace WpfApplication1.Navigation
{
    public class NavigationBehavior:Behavior<NavigationButton>   
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.Click += AssociatedObject_Click;
            base.OnAttached();
        }

        void AssociatedObject_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((Page)AssociatedObject.DataContext).NavigationService.Source = new Uri(AssociatedObject.DestinationUri, UriKind.Relative);
        }
    }
}
```

**NavigationButton**

```
namespace WpfApplication1.Navigation
{
    public class NavigationButton : Button
    {
        NavigationBehavior behavior = new NavigationBehavior();

        public NavigationButton()
        {            
            behavior.Attach(this);
        }

        public string DestinationUri { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Usage :**

```
<nav:NavigationButton Content="Navigate to Page2" DestinationUri="/Navigation/Page2.xaml" />
```

**Important Note**

1. We are using DataContext property in our behavior to get access to the containing page. So, set `this.DataContext = this;` in the constructor of your all pages.

One can try using a common base class / interface to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have interaction triggers extracted but there is a workaround to get this done

you can create a Button in resources with interaction logic in it, and then where needed you can have a content control with content set to your resource.

something like this --

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Button x:Key="MyButton"
     Content="Go to page2">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Source" TargetObject="{Binding NavigationService, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}, Mode=FindAncestor}}">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                <System:Uri>Page2.xaml</System:Uri>
            </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
        </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid>
    <ContentControl Name="MyLocalButton" Content="{StaticResource MyButton}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: But I need to change the Page navigated to

Answer (score 0):

You should put the navigation logic in a command in each page's view model and bind the buttons' Command properties to those commands, or else give the view models each a NextPage property and bind to that.

And create separate buttons in the views. Define a Style in the resource dictionary to make them all look the same.

Defining a Button as a resource is a bad idea. Among other things, there's only one instance of it and it can have only one visual parent, so when you add it to one view it'll vanish from the last. And you run into ugly problems like this one. You're working against XAML, and XAML is already hard enough when you're working with it.

Comment: For a prototype, this goes too far.

Comment: @veritas If you've saved so much time by doing it wrong, why are you on SO asking how to make it work? You asked for a more suitable solution. This is it.

Comment: I might point out that it´s a prototype, maybe I had to use SketchFlow or sth :D

Comment: @veritas If the answer is required to be compatible with some specific tool that forbids the use of conventional XAML, specify that in the question.

Comment: No specific tool is required.